# c++ struct link function

Tags: c++, struct

i have problem with creation a struct function link.

Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*' (Config.h)
Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. (Config.h)

Library.h

```
#include "Config.h"
#include "Struct.h"
```

Struct.h

```
struct COMMANDSTRUCT
{
    char Name[50];
    int Enable;
    int Price;
};
```

Config.cpp

```
   #include "Library.h"

    COMMANDSTRUCT* Config::getIndex(std::string Text)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_COMMANDSTRUCT.size(); i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(m_COMMANDSTRUCT[i].Name, Text.c_str()) == 0)
            {
                return &m_COMMANDSTRUCT[i];
            }
        }

        return NULL;
    }
```

Config.h

```
class Config
{
public:

    static COMMANDSTRUCT* getIndex(std::string Text);
    static std::vector<COMMANDSTRUCT> m_COMMANDSTRUCT;

};
```

usage

```
COMMANDSTRUCT * lpCommand = Config::getIndex("post");
```

Comment: these error messages are incomplete - a compiler usually tells you exactly which line and which piece of code gives him issues

Comment: In what file is `COMMANDSTRUCT` defined?  Have you #included that?

Comment: in Func.cpp included Struct.h file with , struct, yes it's includet

Comment: Does `Struct.h` also include other header files from your project? If so do you have include guards or `#pragma once` in `Struct.h`?

Comment: I have Library.h where include all other H files.... and Library contains Struct

Comment: Edit your question and make clear at which lines those compile errors occur.

Comment: The reason why I ask this is to verify that you do not have a circular include. I mean if `library.h` included `Struct.h` and `Struct.h` also included `library.h` that would be a circular include. Circular includes will cause the kind of behaviour (types being undefined when they are included) that you are seeing.

Comment: @fees Reverse the order of the includes in library.h so that `Struct.h` is before `Config.h`

Comment: @drescherjm its done and that was problem... now only 3 errors http://prntscr.com/4we01t

Comment: For the first warning I expect replacing int with size_t will fix this if the code in the picture is the code that causes the warning. For the error I assume you need to include Price.h somewhere.

Comment: @drescherjm all problems solved. :) tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be the order of the #includes in "Library.h"

Library.h -> includes Config.h (Config class) THEN Struct.h (COMMANDSTRUCT)
Config.h -> depends on COMMANDSTRUCT

So Config.h must be #included AFTER Struct.h

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `struct` declaration so the other files know what that type is.

```
#include "struct.h"  // or whatever you named the file
```

This must be done in `Func.h`, which should then be included in `Func.cpp` so both files have access to that declaration.